# Extract values from arrays using php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have a set of arrays with following details:

```
$thismemberinfo[0]  to $thismemberinfo[7]
$offercurrent[]  = emtpy , will get it values from $thismemberinfo[]
$offerpoints[0] to $offerpoints[7]
$offerpercent[] = emtpy , will get its value from the formula
```

I am filling the values manually.

```
$offercurrent[0]  = $thismemberinfo[0];
$per      = $offercurrent[0]/$offerpoints[0] * 100;
$offerpercent[0] = round($per);


$offercurrent[1]  = $thismemberinfo[1];
$per      = $offercurrent[1]/$offerpoints[1] * 100;
$offerpercent[1] = round($per);
// and so on
```

Question:

I want to automate the process. I have tried this way but does not work:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=7;$i++) {
 $offercurrent[i]  = $thismemberinfo[i];
 $per      = $offercurrent[i]/$offerpoints[i] * 100;
 $offerpercent[i] = round($per);
}
```

Comment: `$offerpercent[$i]` `$i`, see?

Comment: you should also validate `$offerpoints[i]` before using it in division.

Comment: $u_mulder , you are right , if you like,please post it as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you left out the `$` from the `i` variable. `$i`. Try the below. And instead of `$i<=7` , you could also use `$i<=count($offercurrent)`, if that number is dynamic.

```
for ($i=0;$i<=7;$i++) {
    $offercurrent[$i]  = $thismemberinfo[$i];
    $per      = $offercurrent[$i]/$offerpoints[$i] * 100;
    $offerpercent[$i] = round($per);
}
```

Comment: yes , i missed $ , it works well